# Вернуться на папку назад ../index.php не работает

Tags: php, html

`<a href="../index.php?done= <?php printf('%s', $attr);?> ">Back</a>`

Этот код не работает... Почему?

Он остаётся в этой же папке и пытается открыть `index.php`.

Comment: перестаньте строить навигацию и вообще использовать в html разметке относительные ссылки. ни к чему хорошему это не приведет. и уберите из этого кода `printf` он тут попросту ничего не делает в таком виде

Answer (score 0):

Вообще используют обычную маршрутизацию с перенаправлением запроса на index.php через файл htaccess.

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

В таком случае все запросы будут идти на index.php. Теперь вы можете использовать все ссылки через просто `/index.php`.

К тому же не стоит использовать `printf`. Используйте конструкцию `<?= ... ?>`.